# Heating aioli as part of cooking or not

Tags: heat

Just learned how to make aioli a while back and I'm curious if it can be heated while cooking or if it is something intended for the end while plating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's generally presented in a small bowl or container at the table. I've tried using it for cooking, but not with great success. It just separates...
While it can make an emergency substitute for raw garlic or garlic powder in cooking I guess, I'd not call it a satisfactory alternative for either.

Generally in Spain I've seen it served mostly as a dip or spread with bread or toast (though it can also be used at the table like you'd use garlic butter, but again it separates rapidly when heated so is less than ideal).

Comment: Thank you.  I wanted to make a garlic aioli to put on Hasselbeck potatoes but perhaps I'll top them at the end.

Comment: In Valencia it's commonly served instead of mayonnaise with patatas bravas (although I suppose that's covered by your reference to dips) and as an accompaniment to paella.